# How to use special characters in Barcodelib

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using this .Net barcode project to generate a barcode: https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib

Here is my code:

```
BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
        string barcodeText = "SÅÆØ11-1"
        System.Drawing.Image bitmap = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, barcodeText, System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White, 170, 40);
```

The problem is that the special characters - Æ,Ø,Å and - aren't being written at all only "S 11 1" is written out even though CODE128 seem to have these special characters included.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Code 128 Barcode will only support the following characters set range (Char*), which is valid in your testing.

```
https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-128/user-manual/
```

Comment: Yes but then it does support Æ,Ø and Å. These are in the list.